# Select distinct values into one resulting record as a comma separated list

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if it's possible to select distinct values into one resulting record (with one column) and format the values as a comma separated list?

For example:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(lang) as language
FROM
    countries
```

This results into a result set with a number of rows == the amount of distinct languages. But would it be possible to list these values into one record, formatted as a comma separated list?

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GROUP_CONCAT` function should help here:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT lang) AS languages
FROM
    countries
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(lang) SEPARATOR ', ')AS language 
FROM 
    countries
```